# Help to identify a connector

Tags: connector, identification

Can anybody identify the connectors in the two images below and give me some names or links, or whatever? The connectors are from inside a Microsoft Kinect sensor.

[image]
<sup>*Full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRXb9.jpg*</sup>

[image]
<sup>*Full size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4HbI.jpg*</sup>

Comment: As a courtesy to readers who pay by the gigabyte for downloads, why don't you crop these large images down to the essential parts?

Comment: Going by the size of U58 the adjacent J7 footprint is 2mm pitch, and the mystery connector is proportionally a 50-mil pitch board to board stacking connector.  This might have been harder if the image were more tightly cropped ;-)

Comment: Sorry for not cropping the images and sorry if I wasted your traffic.. :(

Comment: If you don't have any luck it's worth measuring that the gap between pins really is 2mm and mention whether it's just the top or bottom board you want to connect to. There are probably a few connectors about that while not identical would be near enough to connect it up.

Comment: @PeterJ - it is not 2mm, but 1.27mm.  The socket is somewhat unique in having exposed wiping fingers.  It is hard to tell but especially given their angular location the pins might be round rather than the more usual square.  There are many connectors which could probably be substituted for these as a pair, but maybe not so many that would mate.  However discrete wires or standard ribbon cable could be soldered to the surface mount leads on each side.